# adding perl script to makefile

Tags: perl, makefile

I have a file called file_read.pl, i want to use it in my makefile.

```
test1:
    rm -rf cov_work *.trn INCA_libs *.dsn 
    $(comp) +UVM_VERBOSITY=UVM_MEDIUM +UVM_TESTNAME=wr_rd_all_registers;
```

how to call that perl script to this target.How to do this?

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: This is my very first time i'm using it in makefile, i don't know how to do it, i was trying that

Comment: What's the relative path from the Makefile to the perl script? Can you call the script directly `/path/to/file_read.pl`, or do you need to prepend `perl`?

Comment: both the files in the same place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can call `perl` with the path to the script as an argument:

```
test1:
    rm -rf cov_work *.trn INCA_libs *.dsn 
    $(comp) +UVM_VERBOSITY=UVM_MEDIUM +UVM_TESTNAME=wr_rd_all_registers
    perl ./file_read.pl
```

If your script is executable and its shebang points to a valid Perl interpreter, you can even just use

```
    ./file_read.pl
```

Comment: i have used it directly, the script is not working. and in the script i have mentioned the shebang